# SwiftUI - MacOS - Draw a rectangle on image to crop

Tags: macos, image, swiftui, crop, gesture

I'm look to crop an image with a rectangle.

I'm displaying an image, and the user will drag a rectangle anywhere in the image.

It will give a new image, corresponding to the part of the image where the user drew the rectangle.

I manage to display the image and draw a rectangle.

Now I need to revert the drag gesture locations back to the original image for cropping, but I cannot find the link.

I have this for now.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        
        Text("Drag a rectangle around the graph to crop the image").padding()

        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack {
                
                Image(nsImage: NSImage(cgImage: inputImage, size: NSSize(width: inputImage.width, height: inputImage.height)))
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global).onChanged { dragGesture in
                       
                        print("START = \(dragGesture.startLocation)")
                        print(" END  = \(dragGesture.location)")
                        print("G - GLOBAL = \(geo.frame(in: .global))")
                        print("G - GLOBAL MAXX = \(geo.frame(in: .global).maxX)")
                        print("G - GLOBAL MINX = \(geo.frame(in: .global).minX)")
                        print("G - GLOBAL MIDX = \(geo.frame(in: .global).midX)")
                        print("G - GLOBAL MAXY = \(geo.frame(in: .global).maxY)")
                        print("G - GLOBAL MINY = \(geo.frame(in: .global).minY)")
                        print("G - GLOBAL MIDY = \(geo.frame(in: .global).midY)")
                        print("G - LOCAL  = \(geo.frame(in: .local))")
                        print("INMG = \(inputImage.width) * \(inputImage.height)")
                        
                        positionX = dragGesture.startLocation.x - geo.frame(in: .global).minX
                        positionY = geo.frame(in: .global).size.height - dragGesture.startLocation.y + geo.frame(in: .global).minY
                        
                        selectionWidth = 1 + abs(dragGesture.startLocation.x - dragGesture.location.x)
                        offsetX = selectionWidth / 2
                        
                        selectionHeight = 1 + abs(dragGesture.startLocation.y - dragGesture.location.y)
                        offsetY = selectionHeight / 2
                        
                        cropWidth = (selectionWidth / geo.frame(in: .global).minX) * CGFloat(inputImage.width)
                        print("X CROP = \(cropWidth)")
                        
                        cropHeight = (selectionHeight / geo.frame(in: .global).height) * CGFloat(inputImage.height)
                        print("Y CROP = \(cropHeight)")
                        
                        let extraWidthSide: CGFloat = ((geo.frame(in: .global).width - geo.frame(in: .global).minX) / 2)
                        print("EXTRA WIDE = \(extraWidthSide)")
                        

                        cropPositionX =  max(0, ((dragGesture.startLocation.x - geo.frame(in: .global).minX - extraWidthSide) / geo.frame(in: .global).minX) * CGFloat(inputImage.width))
                        print("CROP X POS = \(cropPositionX)")
                            

                        cropPositionY = CGFloat(inputImage.height) -
                                (((dragGesture.startLocation.y - geo.frame(in: .global).minY) / geo.frame(in: .global).height) * CGFloat(inputImage.height))
                        print("CROP Y POS = \(cropPositionY)")

                        
                    })
                    .border(Color.black)
                
                    Rectangle()
                        .border(Color.blue, width: 3)
                        .frame(width: selectionWidth, height: selectionHeight)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.clear)
                        .position(x: positionX, y: positionY)
                        .offset(x: offsetX, y: offsetY)
            }
            
        }
        .frame(width: 600, height: 400)
        .padding()
        
        
        
        if let result = resultImage {
            Image(nsImage: NSImage(cgImage: result.cropping(to: CGRect(x: cropPositionX, y: cropPositionY, width: cropWidth, height: cropHeight))!,
                                size: NSSize(width: inputImage.width, height: inputImage.height)))
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .border(Color.purple, width: 2)
                .frame(width: 600, height: 400)
        }
        
        
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Button("Dismiss") {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }.mainButton()
            
            Spacer()
            Button("Crop") {
                resultImage = inputImage.cropping(to: CGRect(x: cropPositionX, y: cropPositionY, width: cropWidth, height: cropHeight))
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }.mainButton()
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    .frame(width: 1400, height: 1000)
```

It "works" for landscape image, but not for portrait.

If you have a solution, or you know a package which does it. I'll take it all.

Thanks,

Nicolas

Comment: Are you trying to reset all the values to their initial state?

Comment: What do you mean?